# How do I change the color of text in an AJAX Barchart?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, ajax

I'm using AJAXToolkit to create a bar chart that displays information about our system but I can't figure out how to change the color of the text in the chart. The text is black against a grey background so it's hard to read.

Things I've tried:

- changing the Theme of the chart to a custom CssClass
- changing the font-color of the chart
- changing the ForeColor on the server side
- changing the class to a custom class

This was the first time I've ever used AJAX so there's a bunch of things I don't know, is there something I'm missing?

Client side code:

```
<div runat="server" id="divStats" class="custom-box container rounded" visible="false">
            <br /><br />
            <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"> </asp:ScriptManager>
            <ajaxToolkit:BarChart ID="BarChart1" runat="server" ChartHeight="600" ChartWidth="900" ChartType="Column" ChartTitle="Players Per Region" ChartTitleColor="#00E676" categoriesaxis="" Theme="Graph-Series">
            </ajaxToolkit:BarChart>
        </div>
```

Server side code:

```
BarChart1.CategoriesAxis = Regions.Remove(0,1);
BarChart1.Series.Add(new AjaxControlToolkit.BarChartSeries { Name="Players per Region", Data = arrValues, BarColor = "#00e676", });
```

[The Chart as it is displaying currently](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HKAeC.png)

Comment: Can't you do it with your own custom css?

Comment: If I can I haven't found a way that works yet because I did try using our custom css and it doesn't change anything

Comment: Inspect and try to change it from browser first, Then write css that should override present class properties by you custom properties. It'll work. Set `!important` every property and take a look

Comment: @Shahjahan holy crap this worked, thanks a lot man

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <style type="text/css">
        .csText {
         color:aqua;
        }
    </style>

 <cc1:BarChart ID="BarChart1" runat="server"  ChartHeight="300" ChartWidth = "450"
       CssClass="csText" >
    </cc1:BarChart>
```

**Note:-**

> You can direct apply css class to ajax tag ....you can find out multiple
>   property in css class ..you can choose as per your need